# Formula to find square root of a natural number using only addition and subtraction

Tags: math, square-root

How to use only addition and subtraction to find out square root of a natural number?
Thanks.
[I have looked over the internet but i didn't find any content related to this problem.]
**Explanation to my problem**: I want to create a c function which will receive only a natural number and return square root of it.
**You may say to use the "sqrt" function** but i just thought of creating one which will utilize addition and subtraction operator to create the square root.
**You don't have to write the program, just writing the formula for it will be just fine. Thanks.**

**Update: This question is not specifically about coding rather about mathematics.(I tagged "c" as it had some link but this question is NOT about coding.)**

Comment: can we use multiplication and division?

Comment: It would be better not to use. But, I am open to see the formula with multiplication and division. @Mitchel0022

Comment: Do you want the result as an int or as a double?

Comment: @DavidRTribble please see the update. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not specifically about coding rather about mathematics.

Comment: And that's why I didn't mention coding in my QUESTION although I did in my EXPLANATION. I also have said that Formula is fine, I DON'T need program. I hope you will understand and upvote so that it doesn't get closed. thanks. @iamnotmaynard

Answer (score 3):

*n<sup>2</sup>* is the equivalent of the sum of the *n* first odd numbers.

You can iterate over the n (consequently adding only the next odd number to the previously calculated sum) until the square is equal or exceeds your number.

```
k = 0
sum = 0
while sum < target:
    k += 1
    sum += 2k-1
if sum > target:
    the target doesn't have integer root
else:
    k is the square root
```

Comment: He wants square root, not square.

Comment: @zch: it's why I should not post on SO at night. I reused my answer in a different way.

Comment: I knew that someone would tell me to use iteration or recursion technique(as I had already thought when nature called me!). That's why I asked to show a formula using only subtraction and addition operator. @mszymborski

Comment: @GaousMuhammadSaklaen: in general square roots are calculated using iterative methods, from the primitive squaring a rectangle method to more interesting ones. I don't think a formula not involving iteration exists.

Comment: @mszymborski and that's the reason I started thinking about it and posted about the topic in stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Would it not be more suitable for math.stackexchange.com? They would likely deliver either proof it does not exist, or a method for doing so.

Comment: I am wondering who is voting negative without understanding what I have asked.

Comment: @mszymborski thanks for suggesting. I will ask again in math.stackexchange.com if it not possible to get an answer here. I hope none copies my question and post it over there, haha...

Comment: @GaousMuhammadSaklaen people are downvoting you because the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, here we primarily discuss code and not maths (unless maths is an important part of the coding question).

Comment: I can clearly see that. Thanks anyway. @Pablo

Answer (score 0):

We can use the fact that `(n+1)² = n² + 2n + 1`.

```
def sqrt(n):
    k = 0
    s = 0
    while s <= n:
        s = s+k+k+1
        k = k+1
    return k-1

print (sqrt(0))     # 0^2
print (sqrt(1))     # 1^2
print (sqrt(2))     # (1.4142135623730951...)^2
print (sqrt(144))   # 12^2
print (sqrt(169))   # 13^2
print (sqrt(196))   # 14^2
print (sqrt(255))   # 15^2
print (sqrt(1000))  # (31.622776601683793...)^2
print (sqrt(2000))  # (44.721359549995796...)^2
```

**UPD**
Sorry, I thought you were asking for code :)

Comment: It's ok. I don't need code. I just needed a formula to find the square root.

Comment: @GaousMuhammadSaklaen I think that can be complicated. There are some methods here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots but they are algorithm-like mostly. Except for some rough approximations.

Comment: Thanks for commenting this link. But, as you can understand, this is not the question I asked. :|  @lcastillov.